# Issue building local docker image

Tags: docker

I am looking to build a docker image and its been literally years since I've had to do this, and I've forgotten most everything I've learned about docker. I wanted to test locally before uploading to GCP.

Re: I'm updating from node:12.*

Anyways, this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx \deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list && wget -qO - https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | apt-key add -


RUN apt update -y && apt install -y nginx build-essential gyp libpng-dev bzip2 autoconf libtool nasm libvips-dev --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && mkdir -p /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json /usr/src/app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install -g node-gyp
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM node:16-alpine
 ---> 2573171e0124
Step 2/6 : RUN echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx \deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list && wget -qO - https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | apt-key add -
 ---> Running in ff30404cf27a
/bin/sh: can't create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list: nonexistent directory
The command '/bin/sh -c echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx \deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list && wget -qO - https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | apt-key add -' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Now, that makes sense because I do NOT have this directory - but I updated this 3 years ago and don't remember coming across it. But more than that - if I don't have that directly locally (I do run nginx) - is there a way to silence it? I tried to create it and got permission issues.

Comment: Alpine isn't a Debian/Ubuntu variant. To install nginx on Alpine, see https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Nginx. I don't see how your Dockerfile *ever* worked in the first place.

Comment: yeah, I used the buster variant and all is good. I forgot about that - thanks for the reminder.

Comment: edit: going with bullseye

Comment: Why not go with a prebuilt nginx image? If you want alpine, `nginx:alpine` should do the trick?

Comment: @ceejayoz Do I even need the 2nd line ie.. "RUN echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch .." IF I am using the node:16-bullseye or 16-buster variant? Over time, I've forgotten why I added that line. I think because I was running an outdated debian image with 12.* node.. ur thoughts?